# Implement an SQL query in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying implement the follow query in LINQ, but I don't find solution:

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AmountMonths
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), pay_date, 112), 1, 6) AS Month
      FROM #tmp 
      GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), pay_date, 112), 1, 6)) AS AmountMonths
```

What I need is get the amounts of months in which the clients made payments, with the condition that there may be months in which no payments have been made.

In C# I tried the following:

```
int amountMonths = payDetail.GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.PayDate)).Count();
```

and

```
int amountMonths = payDetail.GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.PayDate).Month).Count();
```

But I am not getting the expected result.

Comment: Taking a query that works well in SQL and rewriting it for linq is a step backwards. EF will let you send raw SQL to the server. If you have something even remotely complicated and you already have the SQL, use that ability.

Comment: please share some data example, because your second code line is correct. maybe its a string to datetime conversion issue on some rows

Comment: If you don't need the grouping data you can do a DistinctBy instead of a GroupBy.

Comment: Call `EOMONTH(pay_date)` rather than performing a string conversion just to quantize dates to a month level granualrity

Comment: *`Convert.ToDateTime(x.PayDate)`* - `pay_date` / `x.PayDate` already appears to be a date

Comment: *amounts of months* - amount**s** plural? a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` gives only one value

Comment: *Taking a query that works well in SQL and rewriting it for linq is a step backwards* - I do not necessarily agree. I'd add "in some cases". I don't think it's a step backwards here; it's relatively easy to get EF to generate something acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you're using EF Core)

You're almost there. You could do:

```
var amountMonths = context.AmountMonths.GroupBy(c => new { c.PayDate.Year, c.PayDate.Month }).Count();
```

This will translate to something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
      SELECT DATEPART(year, [a].[PayDate]) AS [a]
      FROM [AmountMonths] AS [a]
      GROUP BY DATEPART(year, [a].[PayDate]), DATEPART(month, [a].[Pay_Date])
  ) AS [t]
```

which I'd find preferable over creating a string and chopping it up. EOMONTH isn't a [standard mapped function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions), alas, otherwise it can be used to convert a date to month level granularity

Comment: works, just what I needed! Thank you so much